# Get included method names

Tags: ruby, include, metaprogramming

How I can get all instance method names in the baz method call, which are only present in the Bar module (without other instance methods of this class) ?

```
class Foo
  include Bar

  def a
  end

  def b
  end

  def baz
    #HERE
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo
  include Bar

  def a
  end

  def b()
  end

  def baz
    Bar.instance_methods(false)
  end
end

puts Foo.new.baz
```